# why does qsort() need to know the length of an array and the size of the array element?

Tags: c

I am looking at a basic comparator function which arranges element in a specific order and I came across the `qsort()`.

I see that the `qsort()` requires the length of an array and size of array element as an argument. Why are those two values `size_t length` and `size_t item_size` necessary?

```
qsort(void *array, size_t length, size_t item_size,
      int (*compar)(const void*, const void*));
```

Comment: How else is it supposed to know a) where the array ends and b) how to access any element except for the first (calculating something like array+index*item_size) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the length of the array `qsort` wouldn't know how many elements to sort; without the length, in bytes, of a single element it wouldn't know how to construct a pointer to element at arbitrary position, and move elements around during the sort.

One simple way to understand why you need a particular parameter is to see how it is used in an implementation. Multiple implementations of [`qsort.c`](http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/qsort.c) are available. You can pick one, and see how the parameters in question are used.

Comment: Good call on the link to the apple implementation, much more readable than Gnu's.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `qsort`'s prototype. It accepts a `void*` as a parameter for it's data `array`. So it could really be anything and `qsort` has no way of knowing the size of the elements pointed to, like it would if you were able to pass a distinct typed pointer like `int*`. Where the elements could simply be reference like a normal array.

This means you need to help it along by telling it how large those elements are, along side with the usual length parameter.

`qsort`'s implementation will thus be able to calculate the offset from the address `array` to each of the `length` elements in the array, provide them to your comparator function and shuffle them around as applicable.